# Passing data to <href > tag within <area> tag through code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a .ascx page where I have to display a map.

```
<img width="550" height="296" usemap="#Map" alt="" src="~/map_international.jpg">
<map name="Map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="230,84,233,81,236,77,240,74,244,73,247,73,251,76,254,80,258,82,261,83,265,85,269,88,273,87,271,82,273,78,278,75,278,71,281,67,284,70,287,71,291,71,296,73,303,73,306,69,302,62,306,58,312,58,318,58,322,57,322,51,320,46,318,40,319,35,319,31,312,30,308,30,304,30,298,31,292,33,289,33,287,31,279,29,273,27,266,27,259,28,254,33,249,38,244,40,243,44,246,46,249,46,247,50,245,55,241,57,237,58,234,54,231,50,227,47,225,50,221,52,219,57,223,59,228,60,230,64,230,69,229,72,225,73,220,73,218,77,218,82,219,85,223,85,228,85" 
        href="<%# navigationURL+"id?=12"  %>" alt="Europe" title="Europe" >
</map>
```

navigationURL has the application path where I have assigned value for it in .cs (code behind)

All I want is when I click on this region in map it should navigate to the given path in href.
However when I inspect the element for that region href value is setting empty.
but if i hard code the value in `href="www.google.com"` it will navigate to google page.
But I am not able to pass the data from code behind file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, because your code as typed shouldn't even load a page as it is invalid. It appears you are trying to use a public string named `navigationURL` to set as the href. So your code behind would have something like:

```
public string navigationURL { get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    navigationURL = "someURL?id=12";
}
```

and then your href should look like:

```
href="<%= navigationURL %>"
```

Though it may be easier to skip the variable `navigationURL` and set the href from the code behind. Involves adding an `id`, a `runat="server"` and a closing tag on `area`:

```
<area shape="poly" coords="230,84,233,81,236,77,240,74,244,73,247,73,251,76,254,80,258,82,261,83,265,85,269,88,273,87,271,82,273,78,278,75,278,71,281,67,284,70,287,71,291,71,296,73,303,73,306,69,302,62,306,58,312,58,318,58,322,57,322,51,320,46,318,40,319,35,319,31,312,30,308,30,304,30,298,31,292,33,289,33,287,31,279,29,273,27,266,27,259,28,254,33,249,38,244,40,243,44,246,46,249,46,247,50,245,55,241,57,237,58,234,54,231,50,227,47,225,50,221,52,219,57,223,59,228,60,230,64,230,69,229,72,225,73,220,73,218,77,218,82,219,85,223,85,228,85" 
     id="_area" runat="server" alt="Europe" title="Europe" />
```

Then in code behind, set the url

```
_area.Attributes["href"] = "SomeGreatURL";
```

Comment: thank you . I will try this out. However my page is loading. I am setting the navigationURL in code behind. but id for it ,I am setting in .ascx file.

Comment: Ok. Then it should be something like `href="<%= navigationURL %>?id=12"`.

Comment: href="<%# this.navigationURL + "?articleID="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value")%>"> where value is from my code behind

Comment: You need to include more code. I'm not sure what you mean. It sounds like you are trying to set the value from the code-behind from two different files.

Comment: Hi Mike, using "=" symbol insted of # is right in my case as it a variable and not an object

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#a").click(function(){
        var href = $(this).next("area").attr("linkto");
        alert(href);
    });
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/NE9b7/